# Validation error while uploading Appx file to windows store

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to upload Appx file to windows store but it throws the below error

```
1046: We're only certifying apps that target Windows Phone OS 6.3.1 at
this time. Submit your app again when you hear from us that we're ready
to support this version.
```

I also manually changed the `<OSMinVersion>` and `<OSMaxVersionTested`> version to 6.3.1 in my `package.appxmanifest` file but it still produces the same error.

I build the `.appx` file from visual studio 2012 professional and visual studio 2012 ultimate.Both the packages produces same error while uploading in windows store.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to submit a universal 8.1 .appx which is NOT supported yet by the windows store.
This probably means that you have a working Windows 8.1 app which CAN be submitted, but the Windows PHONE 8.1 portion cannot.